# pandas boxplot returns series type object instead axes

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe like below,

[image: data table sample]

And I am trying to plot size distribution of different species from different projects. Here is I have been trying (very simple code as I am new to python):

```
test=pd.read_excel(file,sheet_name="test",engine='openpyxl')
test.set_index('Species')
test=test.groupby('Project ID')
ax=test.boxplot(column='sizes',by='Species',return_type='axes')
```

The plot is exactly I need (below)
[image: boxplot]

However, this returns ax as series object not axes, that make it hard to handle plot formatting (ie adding y labels, etc...) afterwards, it there any way to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In matplotlib (which is what pandas uses), you always get one "axes" per subplot. Therefore, it makes sense that you have a collection (Series) of axes in your example (two subplots). This is actually good news, because now you can access the subplot you want to style very conveniently by name. Say, for example, you want to add a y-label to the left subplot, you can do:

```py
ax_A = ax.loc["A"].loc["sizes"]
ax_B = ax.loc["B"].loc["sizes"]

ax_A.set_ylabel("My y-label")
```

Full example:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
test = pd.DataFrame({"Project ID": np.random.choice(["A", "B"], 100),
              "Species": np.random.choice(["Plant1", "Plant2", "Plant3"], 100),
              "sizes": np.random.random(100)})


test=test.groupby('Project ID')
ax=test.boxplot(column='sizes',by='Species',return_type='axes')

ax_A = ax.loc["A"].loc["sizes"]
ax_B = ax.loc["B"].loc["sizes"]

ax_A.set_ylabel("My y-label")
```

Comment: @shishi1181 glad it works. please accept the answer if it solves your problem